# PHP - Passing multiple arguments to method containing sprintf()

Tags: php

I am trying to pass multiple arguments to a custom method which contains a sprintf() method. The arguments I am passing will be used in the sprintf() method. Is there a way to do this? I tried the code below but get "too few arguments".

```
<?php
function myMethod($text, $args)
{
    echo sprintf($text, $args);
}

myMethod('"%s" is "%s" method', 'This', 'my');
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [vsprintf()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php) rather than sprintf() is at the heart of any solution, because you pass the arguments as an array:

If you're using PHP 5.6, and can use variadics

```
function myMethod($text, ...$args)
{
    echo vsprintf($text, $args);
}

myMethod('"%s" is "%s" method', 'This', 'my');
```

Otherwise [func_get_args()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) is your friend:

```
function myMethod($text)
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    array_shift($args); // remove $text argument from the $args array
    echo vsprintf($text, $args);
}

myMethod('"%s" is "%s" method', 'This', 'my');
```

Comment: Or you can use [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php): `function myMethod() { call_user_func_array('printf', func_get_args()); }`. It's ugly but it works.

Comment: Wasn't aware of `variadics`. Thanks :)

Comment: @JovanPerovic - variadics require PHP >= 5.6, but they're a lot cleaner to use than func_get_args(), especially if you have additional arguments that you want to maintain independently of the args array

Comment: @JovanPerovic - The flip side of variadics is using "argument unpacking" when calling a function, also very useful - http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php

Comment: Absolutely :) I plan to use full potential of short array syntax (`v5.4`) and this to I am not worried :)